# Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 25391

Tags: android

I face this problem when i try to change background image

in small image it work well and background ghane and program run if i use a big background image i face this errore

Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 25391

my Layout code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background" >

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="202dp"
        android:text="Love Meter"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post the trace ?

Comment: where i can get the trace ?

Comment: this is because theres an out of memory exception that takes place. and the solution you gave is correct, reduce the size!

Answer (score 0):

The Solution is to reduce image size my image size was too big when i reduce it size the problem solved